# python run line in background

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a python scrip similar to

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([2,3,4])

ris1 = function1(x, y) # slow 
ris2 = function2(x, y) # slow
ris3 = function3(x, y) # slow

ris = function4(ris1,ris2,ris3)
```

the function 1,2,3 do not modify the value x,y and they are totally independent. I would like to start the evaluation of ris2 and ris3 even if ris1 is not complete yet. At the end I would like to use all the results together. How can I do that?

I know that it is possible to do some parallelilzation with `joblib` or the `multiprocessing` module but I would like to avoid the use of `map` or `for comprehension` due to the complexity of the syntax.

Comment: Why are the functions slow? What is the bottleneck? If it's, say, processor, you won't gain anything from doing that.

Comment: @DanyCaissy they are slow because they perform heavy computation. I have 30 cores. The first function is internally paralelized up to 10 cores but in this way 20 cores are free and they can be used to evaluate ris2

Answer (score 1):

The possible ways in which asynchronousness can be achieved will introduce more complexities to your code. A better way will be to use multiprocessing or threading libraries. In case of multiprocessing if you don't want to use syntax complexities of map, u can use process method as shown in code below. I am not sure if this complex for you.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([2,3,4])

def function1(x, y, pos):
  output.put((pos, x * y))

def function2(x, y, pos):
  output.put((pos, x * y))

def function3(x, y, pos):
 output.put((pos, x * y))

# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=function1, args=(x, y, 1, output)),
             mp.Process(target=function2, args=(x, y, 2, output)), 
             mp.Process(target=function3, args=(x, y, 3, output))]

# Run processes
for p in processes:
  p.start()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
  p.join()

# Get process results from the output queue
results = [output.get() for p in processes]
results.sort()
results = [r[1] for r in results]

ris = function4(*results)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is a good answer but I would be happy to see also a solution with asynchronous computation so that I can choose the best one for my situation.

Comment: Not to be a downer, but your question is already pretty much ancient for SO, it likely won't get answered anymore. You should just accept his answer and go on with life.

Comment: @Donbeo: If you really want to check asynchronous ways of doing it, you can check for [greenlet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet) but believe me it will make this simple code more complex.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advices. As soon as I have time to try the proposed solution I will accept the anwer